I am creating react app where I have used appwrite for authentication but I am getting a CORS error
I am using appwrite for authentication functionality, I have set the hostname as localhost as I am working in my local environment but I am still getting following CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
I was trying to sign in to my application but I got network request failed
how do I set value of 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header
enter image description here
